# Why aren't the Sunset Squad doing their jobs?

Tags: futurama

The Sunset Squad's objective is to take old people whose lifespan exceeds 160 years, and take them to a secret location in space where they then live in a simulated world waiting for the children to call. In two occasions I can think of, they haven't being doing their job right:

- Farnsworth escaped, and the Reaper bot doesn't capture him after he escaped.
- Mom is obviously over the normal age. Given that Mom was at least 20 before establishing MomCorp, she would have been over the age limit. Another thing would be that she had grey hairs before Farnsworth was completely bald.

Why hasn't the Sunset Squad been doing their jobs regarding these two cases?

Comment: In Mom's case: the sunset squad consists of robots. We've seen that Mom has overrides over all her robots, it would stand to reason she has control over the sunset squad and can stop them from coming after her... Comment and not an answer due to having no evidence.

Comment: just ftr, gray hair can happen and start early in ones life. I started getting grey in my 20's, in my late 30's already getting there, but more salt/pepper look. I have a friend in her 40's who's hair looks grey already, a lot of grey with light blonde. In short, grey hair doesn't say much in terms of age.

Comment: It wasn't little patches of grey hairs.  It was her entire head.  As for control over the Sunset Squad, robots can be made from anybody.  It just so happens that she is the main supplier of robots.

Comment: @blue, in my friends case, it's more like moms with streaks (been confused with old and silver highlights), in reality unless you're looking for it, you can mistake it for either grey or platinum blonde.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Sunset Squad](http://theinfosphere.org/Sunset_Squad_Robot) takes people who have turned 160 years old, and we don't know for certain if [Mom](http://theinfosphere.org/Mom) is this old yet. We know she has to be somewhere around probably 150, since [Farnsworth](http://theinfosphere.org/Professor_Hubert_J._Farnsworth) starts working for her company 131 years prior in [2881](http://theinfosphere.org/2881). In addition, since Mom does have control over all robots *on Earth* (as shown in the episode ["Mother's Day"](http://theinfosphere.org/Mother%27s_Day)) then there's a good chance she may have control over the robots on the [Near Death Star](http://theinfosphere.org/Near_Death_Star) too, and thus be able to stop them from taking her.

Regarding the Professor, there may be some kind of error in the records of the Near Death Star that resulted from the events of the episode ["A Clone of My Own"](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Clone_of_My_Own) when the Professor was broken out by Fry, Leela, and [Cubert](http://theinfosphere.org/Cubert_Farnsworth) (his clone). The group sneaks into the Near Death Star to rescue him by pretending that he has escaped and is being returned, with Fry pretending to be the Professor and Cubert hiding under his robe to give a DNA sample. Having the Professor checked in again when he was already inside may have messed up the internal records such that they wouldn't come looking for him again after he escaped.

I'm imagining some poor programming like the following could explain it:

```
class Retiree: public Human {
  int status;
  ...
public:
  void checked_in () {status++;}
  void died () {status--;}
  void escaped () {status--;}
  bool is_here () {return (status > 0);}
  ...
}
```

Two check-ins and one escape means he still shows as present!

Comment: That is some pretty poor programming...

Comment: So a `Human` can never become a `Retiree`? That doesn't sound right. It would be interesting if somebody managed to escape more than he was checked in. Those poor bots would search for all eternity :)